# MySQL reporting version mismatch due to picking up previous installation

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-workbench

To solve a mysqldump "Workbench was unable to get mysqldump version. Please verify the log for more information.", I opted for the first solution at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44851129/175241

But now workbench does not throw a error, so I check the error log.

```
14:32:30 [ERR][SqlEditorSchemaTree]: Exception querying metadata from mysql.proc, will fallback to SHOW PROCEDURE: Exception: Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
14:32:31 [INF][wb_admin_control.py:query_server_info:714]: WbAdminControl.connect_sql(): The server version stored in the server instance profile was "5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2". Changed to the version reported by the server: "8.0.15"
```

select version(), WB Server Status, mysqld, and mysqldump returns 8.0.15 . So before I start to further debugging, I was wondering if anybody knows what else may have let to my server instance profiled be populated with the wrong MySQL version. I had previously uninstalled this version and upgrade to MySQL 8. When I do which on mysqld and mysqldump, I only get 1 instance of each.

Here is my config:

```
MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 6.3.8 CE build 1228 (64 bit)
Configuration Directory: /home/ras-pc/.mysql/workbench
Data Directory: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
Cairo Version: 1.15.10
OS: Linux 4.15.0-46-generic
CPU: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590T CPU @ 2.00GHz (1970.580MHz) - 7.70GiB RAM
Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

Checking my installation logs on 5 of March, I found

```
Mar 05 08:58:09 raspc systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...^M
Mar 05 08:58:14 raspc systemd[1]: ^[[0;1;39m^[[0;1;31m^[[0;1;39mmysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE^[[0m^M
Mar 05 08:58:14 raspc systemd[1]: ^[[0;1;39m^[[0;1;31m^[[0;1;39mmysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.^[[0m^M
Mar 05 08:58:14 raspc systemd[1]: ^[[0;1;31m^[[0;1;39m^[[0;1;31mFailed to start MySQL Community Server.^[[0m^M
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):^M
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1^M
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:^M
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04); however:^M
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.^M
^M
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):^M
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured^M
Errors were encountered while processing:^M
 mysql-community-server^M
 mysql-server^M
Log ended: 2019-03-05  08:58:15
```

and on 6th of Mar, the server seems to be running properly.

```
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-46.49) ...^M
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...^M
Setting up mysql-server (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...^M
Log ended: 2019-03-06  06:36:00
```

So I presume everything is fine from the installation standpoint. I have been using the database every work day since then.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Are you sure , you have been successfully installed the MySQL version 8?

Comment: Updated question with installation logs. I cannot be 100% sure the installation was successful. It failed, but on the next day, it appears mysql-community-server started properly. I have been using MySQL with triggers, import and export databases without any issue. Only issue is with 'data export', I have to use mysqldump command line.

Comment: *I cannot be 100% sure the installation was successful. **It failed**, but on the next day* This means your MySQL instance is (partially) damaged. Why you are surprised that some operations cannot be performed on a broken instance?

Comment: This problem mysteriously went away.